# Django admin reverse TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

so i was wondering if its possible in Django 1.7.1 to do something like a `reverse Tabular Inline` for example:

Right now i have:

Models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I want my inlines to be something like:

```
class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = get_user_model()

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserInline,
    ]
```

but i get a `<class 'users.admin.UserInline'>: (admin.E202) 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'users.UserProfile'.`

I really need to Use only the UserProfile to create/edit new Users and not the way around like suggested by the inline documentation.

Anyone has an idea on how i can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to extend the user model in Django and looks like you picked the wrong one for your use-case.

Try to extend the built-in user model using inheritance instead.

```
class UserWithProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    relationship_status = models.IntegerField(choices=RS)
    height = models.FloatField()
    ...
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth', 'height']
```

And at settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.UserWithProfile'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am thinking of using AbstractUser and setting AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mynewuser' instead but i believe it should be about the same right?

Comment: Yes, `AbstractUser` has some simple defaults for the mandatory methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler method, where I was able to get this working by creating my own custom modelform:

```
class GirlModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=_('username'), max_length=30,
        help_text=_(
            'Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'
        ),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid'
            )
        ])
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('last name'), max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('email address'))

    # The attribute required must be False because of the clean() workaround
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(), required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Girl
        # fields = [
        #     'degree', 'extra_field'
        # ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.get('initial'):
            kwargs['initial'] = {}

        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            kwargs['initial'].update({
                'username': kwargs['instance'].user.username,
                'first_name': kwargs['instance'].user.first_name,
                'last_name': kwargs['instance'].user.last_name,
                'email': kwargs['instance'].user.email,
            })
        super(GirlModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        """
        This is a nasty workaround and it exists so that we can create/edit
        the user directly in the Userprofiles. The motive is referenced here
        http://stackoverflow.com/q/27235143/977622 and basically the idea is
        to make the built in user NOT REQUIRED and GET or CREATE the user
        object and create a new attribute in the cleaned_data with the user
        object
        """
        cleaned_data = super(GirlModelForm, self).clean()
        user, created = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
            email=cleaned_data['email'],
            defaults={
                'first_name': cleaned_data['first_name'],
                'last_name': cleaned_data['last_name'],
                'username': cleaned_data['username'],
            }
        )

        if not created:
            # If the user exists update it
            user.first_name = cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.username = cleaned_data['username']

        user.save()
        cleaned_data['user'] = user
```

Maybe there is a better way to do it but this is what i was able to do without redoing my models